# In "losing weight" and "gaining weight," are "losing" and "gaining" gerunds or adjectives?

Tags: verbs, nouns, adjectives, gerunds

I saw countless youtube videos and grammar books but *-ing* is too hard.

losing weight

gaining weight

are "losing" and "gaining" gerund or adjective?

Answer (score 1):

In theory, both. Gerunds are verbal forms that function as nouns: in this sense, *gaining weight* has roughly the same meaning as *process where one gains weight*, with *weight* being the object of the verb.

However, they could also be adjectives, modifying *weight*: *the weight that is gaining*. This doesn't make sense for this particular choice of words (which is why I start my answer with "in theory"); but if we take another example:

- *Cheating friends is the worst*: gerund (*the activity where one cheats one's friends is the worst*)
- *Cheating friends are the worst*: adjective (*friends who cheat are the worst*)

Comment: Gerunds are not nouns. Gerunds are verbs—always. Gerund **phrases** function as nouns.  Gerunds do not. A gerund phrase is a verb phrase that is functioning as a noun. The gerund itself cannot. For example “always cheating your friends” has only one noun: *friends*, because it is the object the verb *cheating*. It takes an adverb because it is a verb; if it were a noun, it could not take an adverb.

Comment: @tchrist: I never said gerunds are nouns. Good point, gerund **phrases** function as noun **phrases**, not gerunds themselves as nouns; but a gerund itself can be a gerund phrase ("running is fun"). But most dictionaries I checked carry the simplified definition I quoted.

Comment: Could you please show me then a gerund that functions as a noun? I don't mean a gerund phrase filling the NP slot either.  Please show me a gerund by itself not as a gerund phrase that comports itself after the manner of a noun by accepting adjectives and prepositions joining it to another noun. I don't think these exist because I don't believe gerunds can ever be nouns, only verbs. I am willing to be shown otherwise.

Comment: For the record, the OED2 has: **“A form of the Lat. vb. capable of being construed as a n., but retaining the regimen of the vb. Hence applied to forms functionally equivalent in other langs., e.g. to the Eng. verbal noun in *-ing* when used rather as a part of the vb. than as a n.”**  So the OED says that in English it means an *-ing* “verbal noun” used as a verb rather than as a noun. All that said, [they are not especially consistent](http://www.grammarphobia.com/blog/2016/05/participle-physics.html).

Comment: I (as I already said) agree with you. But I don't have access to OED; meanwhile, M-W: *an English noun formed from a verb by adding -ing*; Cambridge Dictionary: *a word ending in "-ing" that is made from a verb and used like a noun*; Oxford Living Dictionaries: *A verb form which functions as a noun, in Latin ending in -ndum (declinable), in English ending in -ing (e.g. asking in do you mind my asking you?)*; even your own quote says "capable of being construed as a n.". None of them mention noun phrase.

Comment: That said, I think a gerund form can act as a noun or as a verb, but not both: keeping *cooking* as head, *I like delicious cooking* is okay, *I like cooking meat* as well, but not *\*I like delicious cooking meat* (needs either *delicious cooking of meat* or *cooking meat deliciously*).

Comment: Er, not quite. In “I like delicious cooking”, there is **no gerund** at all because that’s a deverbal noun accepting an adjective.  In “I like cooking meat” it is either a participial adjective describing *meat* or else it is a verb whose direct object is *meat*.  Deverbal nouns and participial adjectives are **not gerunds** because they are no longer verbs: they are merely nouns and adjectives. Only in the case taking object complements is the *-ing* word functioning as a verb, and thus only there alone is it a gerund. Once verb-ness is lost, so too is gerund-ness. :)

Comment: @tchrist: I was careful to say "gerund form", not "gerund" :) And I still agree with you :)

Comment: Related: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/154886/pure-verbal-nouns-deverbal-nouns-vs-gerunds