# What part of speech is ‘mountains’ in the sentence “I like climbing mountains”?

Tags: parts-of-speech, syntactic-analysis, ing

I'm trying to understand the grammar of this sentence:

> I like climbing mountains.

Here's what I've got so far:

- "I" is the subject
- "like" is the verb
- I believe "climbing" is a participle
- Maybe "mountains" is the direct object?

Is that right? And are "climbing" and "mountains" both acting as nouns?  Or is the noun "climbing mountains" and "climbing" is an adjective?  I'm getting lost.  Can anyone clarify this for me?

Comment: Grammatically, you can consider *climbing* to be some kind of a noun adjunct or adjective that describes *mountain* (like *chicken* in *chicken soup* or *climbing* in *climbing wall*), but the more natural interpretation would be to take *climbing* as a verb.

Comment: Never liked mountains which climb....

Comment: "mountains" is a noun.  "climbing mountains" is the direct object. "climbing" is either a participle or a gerund, depending on the interpretation of the sentence.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

**tl;dr**: The part of speech of *mountains* is here a **noun**. It’s the direct object of the **verb** *climbing*.

---

How we know that *climbing* is a verb, though, is more work. That’s because it might instead be a noun or an adjective. It’s a verb as just mentioned, but let’s look at all three cases just to make sure.

We’ll assume that for parts of speech, your possible choices are one of noun, verb, adjective, or adverb. Parts of speech like conjunction, preposition, determiner, interjection, and such aren’t really relevant here.

Note that parts of speech can only be single words. Things like subject, predicate, and direct object are not parts of speech. They are syntactic constituents, which can be more than one word.

## *Climbing* as an adjective: “climbing roses”

In

> 1. I like climbing roses.

The word *roses* is the direct object, and it is here being modified by the adjective *climbing*. You can tell it’s an adjective not a noun adjunct because it passes the predicate test:

- The roses are climbing (ones). [TRUE]

You know it isn't a verb here because you can't flip to the infinitive without a change in meaning:

- I like to climb roses. [FALSE]

You can also tell it’s not a verb because adding an adverb of manner to one side means something totally different from what you get adding it to the other side:

- I like quickly climbing roses. [adjective meaning]
- I like climbing roses quickly. [verb meaning]

If *climbing* had been a verb, you would have been able to move *quickly* without changing the meaning. But you can’t.

## *Climbing* as a noun: “climbing gyms”

In

> 2. I like climbing gyms.

Here now *gyms* is the direct object of *like*, but *climbing* has now become a noun modifying *gyms*, not an adjective modifying *gyms*. You can tell this because it fails the predicate test:

- The gyms are climbing. [FALSE]

Therefore these are gyms that are **for** climbing, and so *climbing* is here a noun. You can think of *climbing-gyms* as a compound noun.

The stress has also shifted.

You know it's a noun because you can add other customary components of a noun phrase like quantifiers and adjectives:

- I like some easy climbing gyms.

Because you can do that, you know it’s not a verb there.

## *Climbing* as a verb: “climbing mountains”

In

> 3. I like climbing mountains.

The direct object of the verb *like* is **the *entire* non-finite verb phrase** *“climbing mountains”*, where *mountains* is in turn the direct object of the non-finite verb *climbing*.  Since only verbs can have direct objects and *mountains* is the direct object of *climbing*, that means that *climbing* must be being used as a verb here.

Verbs not only take objects, they can also take adverbs of manner. So for example:

- I like quickly climbing mountains.
- I like climbing mountains quickly.

Because you can freely move *quickly* and the two sentences above still mean the same thing, you know that *quickly* is modifying *climbing* as a verb. If it were doing so as an adjective, you would **not** be able to move *quickly* around like that without shifting the meaning.

In other words, if they had meant different things after adverbial movement, then these would just be mountains that happened to be quickly climbing ones, like quickly climbing roses. But since that’s not what this means, it’s a verb.

Again, the entire verb phrase, not any single word, is the direct object of *like*, but *climbing* is clearly a verb because only verbs take direct objects and relocatable adverbs of manner in this fashion.

In this instance, you can be sure it's a verb because you can flip it from the one sort of non-finite verb phrase to the other kind without any change in meaning:

- I like to climb mountains.
- I like to quickly climb mountains.
- I like to climb mountains quickly.

Since that means the same thing, both *climbing* and *to climb* are verbs here.

---

Some posters have suggested that this instance of *climbing* is a noun. It can’t be, as I’ve just demonstrated that it has a direct object, which only a verb can have.

But if you still aren’t convinced, let’s try to do noun-things to this would-be noun. If it were actually a noun, you would be able to modify it with an adjective like *dangerous*.

- I like ✻dangerous climbing mountains. [**UNGRAMMATICAL**]

That shows that *climbing* is not a noun here, since the result is ungrammatical when you try to add an adjective to it.

It’s a verb. Just a verb: not a noun, not an adjective.

---

#### *postscript*

I’m just glad you didn’t ask what *climbing* was in

> 4. I like climbing climbing mountain roses climbing mountain climbing gyms.

For up that wall [climb climbing buffalo climbing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffalo_buffalo_Buffalo_buffalo_buffalo_buffalo_Buffalo_buffalo). :)

Comment: +1 for the thorough explanation (but an emphatic +1 for the postscript)

Comment: Isn't your second example also adjectival -- "climbing gyms"? "Climbing" simply describes the type of gym. Frankly I can't think of any sentence which would just use "climbing" by itself as a noun. Climb, yes; climbing, not.

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas No, *climbing* is a noun in *climbing gyms* because the gyms are gyms **for** climbing; they aren't themselves actually climbing.  It's like how *running shoes* has a noun modifying a noun, but *running water* has an adjective doing so. People do consider climbing a sport; you can add adjectives to it and have *beginning climbing*, *easy climbing*, *advanced climbing*, etc., and because adjectives can't modify other adjectives we know that *climbing* can be, and is there, a noun.

Comment: “I like **climbing** mountains” OR “I like **to climb** mountains”. Both practically mean the same, but the latter *proves* that climb is a verb here.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Indeed so, which is why I saved that point for last, since it was the very point I had set out to prove after my short-and-simply/TLDR pronouncement at the top of the posting. I had to disprove other possibilities first, because I didn't want people thinking that these were somehow mountains which climbed. :)

Comment: I may be wrong, but I think Hagen got it correct below. This could have been written as "I like mountain climbing", which illustrates that what follows 'like' is the direct object, so climbing mountains is acting like a noun (a gerund), much like jogging in the sentence: 'I like jogging'.  You can also flip it around and see it more clearly by saying: "Climbing mountains is my favorite pastime."

Comment: @Byron No, "climbing mountains" is not a noun. It can't be: it's two words. It's a non-finite verb phrase that's acting as the grammatical direct object of the verb *like*. The head of the verb phrase "climbing mountains" is *climbing* and the direct object of the verb *like* is *mountains*.  Yes, non-finite verb phrases can be used in places where the grammar expects a noun phrase, but that doesn't mean that it turns them into noun phrases. It does not. They're still verb phrases not noun phrases, whether those are written as *to climb mountains* or written as *climbing mountains*.

Comment: An excellent explanation. But I want to detect something, why couldn’t we think of it this way; Consider **climbing** as an adjective: I like the mountains that are specifically used for **climbing**. So we could write the sentence: I like **climbing** mountains? @tchrist

Comment: @BavyanYaldo Sure, but nobody would know you meant. :) The verbal collocation is far too common for anyone ever to think of anything else. Say if you must: "I like mountains made for climbing" or some such thing.

Comment: But, but, but,... the question was what is "mountains" in the sentence, not "what is 'climbing'".

Comment: @DWin Which is why the first thing said is that *mountains* is a noun, and that it’s the direct object of the verb *climbing*. But proving that requires some work, especially since some folks think *mountains* might be the direct object of *like*. It’s not: the direct object of *like* is the noun clause *“climbing mountains”*, which is a non-finite verb phrase whose head is the verb *climbing*. You cannot figure out what *mountains* is without understanding *climbing*, which is the hard part.

Comment: @tchrist Saying that the "mountains that are for climbing" interpretation (in which climbing is a noun) is much less common is not the same thing are saying it **can't** be a noun. Imagine that the statement "I like climbing mountains" is a reply to a question "What is your favourite kind of mountain?" In fact in that context "I like ✻dangerous climbing mountains" is also perfectly grammatical and easily understood, so I don't think your attempt to "prove" that "climbing" cannot be a noun there actually works.

Comment: @tchrist Instead of trying to claim it's impossible for climbing to be a noun there, I think this answer would be more accurate to say something like "it's technically ambiguous, but that the verb interpretation is so common that it predominates in the absence context clearly requiring the noun interpretation."

Comment: @tchrist Makes sense now. Unlike language, grammar is usually very logical, and your logic is good.

Comment: @Ben The reason I used three different words — *roses, gyms, mountains* — following *climbing* is because I wanted clear and obvious cases that would quickly make sense to everyone reading their normal meanings into them to illustrate the three part-of-speech possibilities for the word following it: adjective, noun, or verb. Obviously you can twist any of those into any of the others if you try hard enough to create the contextual setup necessary to pull so improbable a thing off, but I didn't want to complicate stuff.

Comment: @tchrist My point was that I think you've actually made it *more* complicated by saying "this is the only correct way to interpret this sentence" and then trying to defend that position, instead of just admitting to the context-dependency (which is after all perfectly normal for all human languages). I don't think anyone would have disagreed if you had claimed "this is the *most likely* interpretation of the sentence" instead of saying "this is the only correct interpretation of the sentence"..

Comment: @Ben Ok, I see what you're saying now. I'll see what I can do.

Comment: 'Note that parts of speech can only be single words.' Unless they're open compound nouns. Or arguably, open compound prepositions ('on top of'].

Answer (score 3):

You're asking multiple questions about this sentence:

> *I like climbing mountains.*

So I'll try and tackle them one by one.

**(1) In the title, you ask about the part of speech of *mountains*.**

These are parts of speech in English:

> **noun**, **verb**, adjective, adverb, preposition, determiner, conjunction, interjection

The suffix *-s* of *mountains* can only be attached to a noun or a verb. Since the word *mountain* here is [used to identify any of a class of people, places, or things](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/noun) and is not [used to describe an action, state, or occurrence](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/verb), it is a noun.

**(2) Is *climbing* a participle?**

There's this ongoing confusion as to whether to call an -ing form **a present participle** or **a gerund** or even **a gerund-participle**. Resolving this confusion alone deserves a separate question, and it's not even clear whether there's a consensus among grammarians on this matter. Therefore, it's not really possible here to determine which term is the right one.

But one thing is clear: None of these terms is a part of speech. The part of speech of *climbing* is a verb, because it takes *mountains* as a direct object, which answers the following question:

**(3) Is *mountains* the direct object of *climbing*?**
Yes.

**(4) Are *climbing* and *mountains* both acting as nouns? Or is *climbing mountains* a noun and *climbing* an adjective?**

The only supposed problem of treating *climbing* as a verb is that the verb *like* seems to take *climbing* as a complement. But this is an illusion. It's not *climbing* that the verb *like* takes as a complement; it's *climbing mountains* as a whole. Now, *climbing mountains* cannot be any part of speech, because it's not a word but a clause consisting of a verb (*climbing*) and its direct object (*mountains*).

So, it's better to think of -ing as a tool to make the clause *climb mountains* function as a complement of the verb *like*. This point becomes clear when we consider this pair side by side:

> *I like climbing mountains.*
>
> *I like climbing.*

In the latter, *climbing* should be categorized not as a verb but as a noun.

Comment: +1 for a short but solid analysis not only leading directly  to the correct answer but also dispelling the whole "gerund clause" distraction and presenting a novel suggestion for how to think of these as a "tool" for creating suitable substantive-standins for a verb's arguments.

Answer (score 0):

Speaking of *parts of speech*, we have

- "I" is a personal pronoun
- "like" is a (transitive) verb
- "climbing" is a noun (specifically, the gerund of *to climb*)
- "mountains" is a noun
- one may consider the whole *gerund phrase* "climbing mountains" as a noun

Regarding their syntactic functions

- "I" is the subject
- "like" is the predicate
- "climbing mountains" is the (direct) object, which here comes in the shape of a *gerund phrase*; within that, "mountains" is the gerund *complement* (sometimes also called the gerund *object* because it would be the object if the gerund were a verb: "... climb mountains" )

Comment: *Climbing* is not a noun. It is a verb. That's the only way it can have a direct object of *mountains*. Only verbs have direct objects, never nouns. If it were a noun you could add adjectives like *dangerous* to it, and you cannot. “I like ✻dangerous climbing mountains" is ungrammatical. Therefore *climbing* is not a noun. *Mountains* is, however. Notice you can add a movable adverb of manner — like *quickly* — to either side of that verb phrase, thus proving it a verb phrase not a noun phrase. The head of that VP is the verb *climbing*.

Comment: @tchrist According to, uh,  [you](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/205404/6630), a gerund is both a verb and a noun.

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft My answer there needs work; I've deleted it till I can fix it. This whole simultaneity thing is exactly why I asked [this question and received this definitive answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/389561/2085).