# Is the following a gerund or participle in this sentence?

Tags: gerunds, participles

> I'm not feeling myself today.

In the sentence above, is 'feeling' a gerund or participle? (I understand that the main verb is 'am', from which I can then ascertain that it is at least one of these two non-finite verb forms.) The phrase 'feeling myself' seems like something that could be swapped out for another adjective -'I'm not happy'; 'I'm not certain' - which makes me think participle. But the fact that it is functioning as the object of the sentence (I think? Or is this a verb without an object?) makes me think gerund.

For context:

> "It's alright. You're probably right. I'm not feeling myself today. Ignore me."

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Please be as technical as you can!

Comment: Noun, verb, or adjective: pick one. Also, if *myself* is the object of *feeling*, then it's like feeling the edge of a sharp knife, which is probably not a good idea. That or something unprintable, which is an even worse idea.

Comment: I think the author is implying the character is not feeling _like_ themselves today (they are reprimanding themselves for being rude to another character). Would that make 'feeling' just another normal verb? Apologies - still very confused here.

Comment: Try looking at *am feeling* as the whole verb there.

Comment: Thank you, Yosef, that really cleared it all up - tchrist's post too. I guess it's more likely that 'am feeling' is just a normal verb, though it is ambiguous here. I think I've been doing this stuff for too long today.

Comment: No: "am feeling” is **not** a single syntactic unit, i.e. not a single verb, but two verbs, “am” + “feeling”, where the present participle “feeling” serves as complement of “am” to form the progressive aspect. "Be" is a catenative verb here, so this is a catenative construction where the subordinate clause "feeling myself today" is its catenative **complement**. There's no object: "myself" is an obligatory predicative complement. Note, though, that there's no need to distinguish gerunds and present participles: simply call them ‘gerund-participles’ (see herisson's answer below).

Answer (score 1):

> I'm not feeling myself today.

This is a "progressive" or "continuous" construction, where a finite inflected form of the auxiliary BE is followed by an *-ing* form of the verb FEEL.

I think that currently, in approaches to English grammar that treat the gerund as a distinct form from the *-ing* participle, the *-ing* form in this construction is generally categorized a participle (the "present", "progressive", or "active" participle).

Its historical origin appears to be more arguable: äüö's answer to the prior question [progressive forms: participle or gerund?](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/167769/77227) cites a source that argues that there were originally two distinct constructions, one with BE + a present participle, and one with BE + preposition + gerund, that ended up being conflated in Middle English.

The *Cambridge Grammar of the English Language* (Huddleston and Pullum, 2002) does not treat the gerund and present participle as distinct inflected forms: it argues for calling the *-ing* form of verbs the "gerund-participle" rather than using separate terms "gerund" and "present participle" depending on the use.

---

BE does not take an object. You might be confusing the concepts of "object" and "complement". A complement is, roughly, some element that "completes" the meaning of a phrase; objects are just one type of complement. When the complement of a verb is a noun phrase, that noun phrase is called the "(direct) object" of the verb; but verbs can take other types of complements, such as preposition phrases ("I am **in the garden**") or adjective phrases, as in your example ("I'm not **happy**").