# Why is the present participle always regular?

Tags: verbs, present-participles

Most rules of the English language have some irregularity [citation needed].

Forming the present participle isn't one of them: take the infinitive, and add the suffix -ing (in speech. In writing, [it's a bit more complicated](http://www.studyenglishtoday.net/present-participle.html) due to the irregularities of English orthography in general - but those irregularities are themselves regular, if that makes sense).

Why is this? Even "to be", the most irregular verb in English (with a whopping *eight* distinct forms, almost every one irregular), has a regular present participle.

Comment: Because you  need the -ing suffix to form a present participle. “*The -ing of Modern English in its participial (adjectival) use comes from Middle English -inge, -ynge, supplanting the earlier -inde, -ende, -and, from the Old English present participle ending -ende.*” https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/-ing

Comment: Related: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/13860/origin-of-ing

Comment: @user66974 You also need the -s suffix to form the 3rd person singular. And yet, four verbs still form it irregularly - is, has, does and says (the last two only in pronunciation). There are no such forms for the present participle, even "being" is completely regular!

Comment: @user66974 The question appears to be "Why is there never any change in the 'prefix' part of the present participle?" It's not about *-ing* per se.

Comment: That's a very good question, and it is about the _-ing_ verbal suffix, and the present participle it forms. It's one of the few [inflections left in English](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/Inflection.pdf), and it's the only regular one. All of the others have always been irregular, so it's not a matter of having lost all the regular inflections during the lingering death of English morphology. In fact, it's an odd linguistic phenomenon, and it doesn't have an explanation.

Comment: The Irish have an insoluble Question. The English have ... English.

Comment: Asking why a language's grammar, morphology, phonetics, or anything else is the way it is, in some ultimate sense, is futile. There will never be any answer other than *convention*.